# Create SQL Table for Number Referencing

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry, I'm still fairly new at all of this. I need to create a SQL table that has two columns: PrimaryNumber, ThousandRange

PrimaryNumber should be filled with with integers from 1 - 20,000.
ThousandRange should be filled with PrimaryNumber's respective range.

For example:

```
PrimaryNumber       ThousandRange
1000                1000-1999
1001                1000-1999
1002                1000-1999
1003                1000-1999
...                 ...
2000                2000-2999
2001                2000-2999
2002                2000-2999
2003                2000-2999
```

And so on.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

One method is rather complex `case` expression.  A more fun method is to play with strings and arithmetic:

```
select (floor(primarynumber / 1000)*1000 || '-' ||
        (floor(primarynumber / 1000)*1000 + 999)
       ) as thousandrange
```

This uses ANSI-standard syntax.  This or something similar should work in most databases.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/13585), for instance, is a SQL Fiddle.

EDIT:

You want to create the table as well.  And SQL Server is a little trickier.  Here is one method:

```
with n as (
      select 1000 as n union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n < 20000
     )
select n as primarynumber,
       replace(replace('[1]-[2]', '[1]', floor(n / 1000)*1000), '[2]', floor(n / 1000)*1000 + 999) as thousandrange
from n
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/BXYXYL99509) is another demonstration.

Comment: Should the second PrimaryNumber reference be ThousandRange? From looking at it, and forgive my ignorance, I'm not sure how the "range" gets into the ThousandRange column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
DECLARE @startnum INT=1000 
DECLARE @endnum INT=20000 

;WITH cte (primarynumber, thousandrange) 
     AS (SELECT @startnum, 
                @startnum 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT primarynumber + 1, 
                ( primarynumber + 1 ) - ( ( primarynumber + 1 ) % 1000 ) 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  primarynumber < @endnum) 


SELECT primarynumber, 
       Cast(thousandrange AS NVARCHAR(max)) + '-' + Cast(thousandrange+999 AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS thousandrange 
FROM   cte 
OPTION (maxrecursion 20000)
```

Output...

```
+---------------+---------------+
| primarynumber | thousandrange |
+---------------+---------------+
| 1000          | 1000-1999     |
| 1001          | 1000-1999     |
| 1002          | 1000-1999     |
| ---           |               |
| 2783          | 2000-2999     |
| 2784          | 2000-2999     |
| 2785          | 2000-2999     |
| ---           |               |
| 7259          | 7000-7999     |
| 7260          | 7000-7999     |
| 7261          | 7000-7999     |
| ---           |               |
| 13737         | 13000-13999   |
| 13738         | 13000-13999   |
| 13739         | 13000-13999   |
| ---           |               |
| 17762         | 17000-17999   |
| 17763         | 17000-17999   |
| 17764         | 17000-17999   |
| ---           |               |
| 19998         | 19000-19999   |
| 19999         | 19000-19999   |
| 20000         | 20000-20999   |
+---------------+---------------+
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/15728/0

Answer (score 0):

You're just doing this once so it really doesn't need to be a single "set-based" query. A simple loop will work perfectly fine.

```
create table N (PrimaryNumber int not null, ThousandRange varchar(12) not null);

declare @n int = 1;
while @n <= 20000
begin
    insert into N (PrimaryNumber, ThousandRange) values
        (@n, cast(@n / 1000 * 1000 as varchar(8)) + '-' +
             cast(@n / 1000 * 1000 + 999 as varchar(8));
    set @n = @n + 1;
end
commit;
```

In SQL Server this uses standard integer division.